# how to change a height layout as animation (programmatically)

Tags: android, android-animation

how to change a height layout programatically as animation?

first :

[image]

after :

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Heey Amigo,

After testing my code, i saw a small issue. Because i used `"scaleY"` it just "stretches" the view. That means if there is some text or something in the view, it will just stretch it and won't look nice. Try with the `ValueAnimator` instead, its works more smooth

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(!isBig){
        ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(100, 200);
        va.setDuration(400);
        va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                v.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        });
        va.start();
        isBig = true;
    }
    else{
        ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(200, 100);
        va.setDuration(400);
        va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                v.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        });
        va.start();
        isBig = false;
    }
}
```

The XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="My Layout"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Old Answer**
You can use the ObjectAnimator, just remeber to set the `pivotY(0)` so it only moves on the bottom. Play with it yourself to match it your needs :)

```
private boolean isBig = false;

...

public void onClick(View v)
{
    v.setPivotY(0f);
    if(!isBig){
        ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "scaleY", 2f);
        scaleY.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        scaleY.start();
        isBig = true;
    }
    else{
        ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "scaleY", 1f);
        scaleY.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        scaleY.start();
        isBig = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. Use the `ValueAnimator` instead, it will work better if you have some text or something else inside the view/layout